# Installing hadoop on Centos 7 but command is not working

Tags: hadoop, centos, vmware, centos7

I am trying to install cluster hadoop on centos7. But command is not responding , I manually download the hadoop from this [link](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.0/hadoop-2.7.0.tar.gz) on windows and then copy on VMware and installing using this command but this is not working.

[image]

Comment: Argument order matters. Put the `-xJv` flags **before** the filename.

Comment: I changed it before, but it not respond for like 10/15 minutes so i cancel it

Comment: You missed the `f` flag which told it what file to operate on. You want `tar -xvf hadoop-2.7.0.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you run:

```
tar xvzf /home/hadoop.2.7.0.tar.gz
```

Also could you please run and paste results for:

```
du /home/hadoop.2.7.0.tar.gz
tar tvzf /home/hadoop.2.7.0.tar.gz
md5sum /home/hadoop.2.7.0.tar.gz
```

You can find distribution with checksums [here](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.0/)